# How to implement robust and secure session management (in general, and in Next.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, https

I am using Next.js and want to properly implement session management into this serverless architecture. I checked out nextauth but I am not really a fan and it doesn't implement some things I think I might need, so just trying to keep things simple and do it myself. I also read through express-session where most of this code comes from.

Here is the bulk of the session management utilities:

```
import stringifyJSON from './stringify-json'
import moment from 'moment'
import knex from 'initializers/knex'
const crypto = require('crypto')
const cookie = require('cookie')
const signature = require('cookie-signature')

const random = (size) => {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    crypto.randomBytes(size, function(err, rnd) {
      if (err) return rej(err)
      res(rnd)
    })
  })
}

export const generateSessionId = async () => {
  const sessionIdBuffer = await random(32)
  const sessionId = sessionIdBuffer.toString('hex')
  return sessionId
}

export function getcookie(cookieHeader, name, secret) {
  var raw;
  var val;

  var cookies = cookie.parse(cookieHeader);

  raw = cookies[name];

  if (raw) {
    if (raw.substr(0, 2) === 's:') {
      val = signature.unsign(raw.slice(2), secret)

      if (val === false) {
        val = undefined;
      }
    } else {
    }
  }

  return val
}

export function setcookie(res, name, val, secret, options) {
  var signed = 's:' + signature.sign(val, secret);
  var data = cookie.serialize(name, signed, options);

  var prev = res.getHeader('Set-Cookie') || []
  var header = Array.isArray(prev) ? prev.concat(data) : [prev, data];

  res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', header)
}

export async function resolvePublicSession(req, res) {
  const privateSession = await resolvePrivateSession(req, res)
  const user = await knex.from('user').select('*').where('id', privateSession.user_id).first()

  if (!user.is_guest) {
    const avatar = await knex.from('image')
      .where('id', user.avatar_id)
      .select('*')
      .first()

    if (avatar) {
      avatar.sources = await knex.from('image_source')
        .where('image_id', avatar.id)
        .returning('*')
        .all()

      user.avatar = avatar
    }
  }

  const session = {
    user,
    ip: req.headers['x-real-ip'] || req.connection.remoteAddress,
    // csrfToken
  }

  return JSON.parse(stringifyJSON(session))
}

export async function resolvePrivateSession(req, res) {
  let session

  if (req.headers.cookie) {
    // TODO: move these secrets/names into config somewhere
    const token = getcookie(req.headers.cookie, 'head', 'a secret')

    if (token) {
      session = await knex('session')
        .select('*')
        .where('token', token)
        .first()

      if (session) {
        if (session.expires_at <= new Date) {
          session.token = await generateSessionId()
          session.expires_at = moment().add('days', 30).toDate()
          await knex('session').where('token', token)
            .update({
              token: session.token,
              expires_at: session.expires_at
            })
        }
      }
    }
  }

  if (!session) {
    const [guestUser] = await knex('user').insert({ is_guest: true })
    const newToken = await generateSessionId()
    const expires_at = moment().add('days', 30).toDate()
    const sessions = await knex('session')
      .returning('*')
      .insert({
        user_id: guestUser.id,
        token: newToken,
        expires_at
      })
    session = sessions[0]
  }

  setcookie(res, 'head', session.token, 'a secret', {
    // maxAge:
    // domain:
    path: '/',
    expires: session.expires_at,
    httpOnly: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
    secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
    sameSite: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
  })

  return session
}
```

And here is how it might be used in a server API call:

```
export default async function(req, res) {
  const { code } = req.query
  try {
    const session = await sessionController.resolve(req, res)
    const creds = await linkedinController.getAccessToken(code)
    await linkedinController.upsertAccount(session, creds)
    const user = await userController.getFromSession(session)
    if (user.is_guest) {
      await userController.promote(user)
    }
    res.redirect(`/name`)
  } catch (e) {

  }
}
```

And here is how it might be used on the frontend:

```
export default function MyPage({ session }) {
  // handle session object, and render view
}

export async function getServerSideProps({ req, res }) {
  const sessionController = require('../utils/session')
  const session = await sessionController.resolvePublicSession(req, res)

  return {
    props: { session },
  }
}
```

What is wrong with and/or missing from making this a *robust* session management system? I think I still need to add csrf tokens somewhere in the mix (not sure where yet, maybe you can advise on that). But other than that I think this is all you really need. What else do I need and/or what am I doing wrong?

The bulk of the cookie reading/writing code comes straight out of [express-session](https://github.com/expressjs/session) (slightly modified to allow for only one secret, not sure why they used an array of secrets).

Basically how it works is, inside of a Next.js API request handler, you call `sessionController.resolvePrivateSession`, which just results in a session object straight from the sessions table in the database, which has `token` (the unique random bytes in hex), and the expires_at time, which currently I am not sure how to use this, how do I use/implement the expires_at feature?

The process of "returning a session object from the db" really is quite involved. First it tries parsing the cookie, which might look like this:

```
s:fd51d213b6935caf5d987dac8dbadf3674dba89dac5d976ab56b5ba88cdf731b.O9jinFhrd7F/R+oazU3+5pxzAaBwbybt+meJTjcQKLg
```

Noticing the `s:`, it knows to try and verify the token. That uses a standard node.js library to unsign the cookie, which gives back `false` or the original token. I'm not entirely sure how this works internally, but I assume it's correct. Have more reading to do there.

Then it tries to find the session from the DB using that `token` it got from the cookie. If it finds it, it checks if the session is expired, in which case I'm not sure if I should just generate a new token or what. Oh I also have a "guest" sort of system in here, so there is *always* a user (so things can be tracked more systematically). This I think could be spammed and create a bunch of users, so periodically the sessions with guest users should just be cleared from the db, but that's a tangent. But given it finds the session, we can now find the `user_id` stored on the session db object, and go from there and do what we need. That is the whole purpose of this function.

But then just before returning the session + user_id, it writes the signed cookie to the header in the response. I don't think anything else needs to be passed in as a string to the encoder, but express-session passed in a hash of the entire JSON.stringify(sessionObject), which seems like a lot and unnecessary so I cut it out. But then we have the cookie written which has the signed token obscurified, so we can retrieve it in the next request. **Is that all that needs to happen for session management?** What am I missing?

Key questions:

- What do you do with the expires_at field on the session db object?
- Does anything else need to be added to make this more secure?